# I am getting different value when printing and appending same variable to a list, Why is that?

Tags: python, nested-lists

The first code gives me the output I want but I want the dct to append to a list so I can use the values later. When I try to do that it gives me a different output. Why?

```
lst = [{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3 },{'e' : 1, 'f' : 2, 'g': 3}]
e = 0
while e < len(lst):
    for k in lst[e]:
        dct = {}
        x = lst[e][k]
        for key, value in lst[e].items():
            lst[e][key] = (value - x)
            dct[k] = (lst[e])
        print(dct)
    e += 1

output(lst) = {'a': {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}}
              {'b': {'a': -1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}}
              {'c': {'a': -2, 'b': -1, 'c': 0}}
              {'e': {'e': 0, 'f': 1, 'g': 2}}
              {'f': {'e': -1, 'f': 0, 'g': 1}}
              {'g': {'e': -2, 'f': -1, 'g': 0}}
```

So the following is what I tried to do to save it in a list

```
e = 0
lst2 = []
while e < len(lst):
    for k in lst[e]:
        dct = {}
        x = lst[e][k]
        for key, value in lst[e].items():
            lst[e][key] = (value - x)
            dct[k] = (lst[e])
        lst2.append(dct)        
    e += 1
print(lst2)
```

But the output when I print that list gives me the same value for every key in the different dictionaries.

```
Output(lst2)= [{'a': {'a': -2, 'b': -1, 'c': 0}}, 
               {'b': {'a': -2, 'b': -1, 'c': 0}}, 
               {'c': {'a': -2, 'b': -1, 'c': 0}}, 
               {'e': {'e': -2, 'f': -1, 'g': 0}}, 
               {'f': {'e': -2, 'f': -1, 'g': 0}}, 
               {'g': {'e': -2, 'f': -1, 'g': 0}}]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a tag for the programming language you're using, otherwise people who know about that language won't find your question.

Comment: You are modifying the mutable `lst` and using that same object at each iteration.

Comment: To expand on @j1-lee's comment, you're seeing the effects of a list of references to mutable objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your existing code, change

```py
lst2.append(dct)
```

to

```py
lst2.append(dct.copy())
```

(and to understand why, read up on [lists, references, and mutability](http://www.compciv.org/guides/python/fundamentals/lists-mutability/).)

Or, if you want to rewrite your code, you might use

```py
list_ = [{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 3 },{'e' : 1, 'f' : 2, 'g': 3}]

result = {}
for d in list_:
    for key, value in d.items():
        result[key] = {k:d[k]-value for k in d}
```

which gives

```py
>>> print(result)
{'a': {'a':  0, 'b':  1, 'c': 2},
 'b': {'a': -1, 'b':  0, 'c': 1},
 'c': {'a': -2, 'b': -1, 'c': 0},
 'e': {'e':  0, 'f':  1, 'g': 2},
 'f': {'e': -1, 'f':  0, 'g': 1},
 'g': {'e': -2, 'f': -1, 'g': 0},
}
```

(and if you're a fan of code-golf, here's a one-liner:)

```py
result = {key: {k:d[k]-value for k in d} for d in list_ for key,value in d.items()}
```